# Show that the imbedding $C^{m+1}(\overline{\Omega}) \to C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Let $C^m (\overline{\Omega})$ be the Banach space of functions such that each partial derivative $D^{\alpha}f$, $|\alpha| \le m,$ exists and is uniformly continuous on $\Omega$. The norm is given by

$$||f||_{C^m (\overline{\Omega})} = \operatorname{max}_{|\alpha| \le m} \operatorname{sup}_{x \in \Omega} |D^{\alpha}f(x)|. $$

Furthermore, let $C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ be the Banach subspace of functions $ f \in C^m (\overline{\Omega})$ such that each $D^{\alpha}f, |\alpha| \le m,$ satisfies a Holder condition with exponent $1$. The norm on this space is given by

$$||f||_{C^{m,1} (\overline{\Omega})}=||f||_{C^m (\overline{\Omega})} + \operatorname{max}_{|\alpha| \le m} \operatorname{sup}_{x,y \in \Omega, x \neq y} \frac{|D^{\alpha}f(x)-D^{\alpha}f(y)|}{|x-y|}.  $$

Assume that we know that $C^{m+1}(\overline{\Omega})$ is contained in $C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ and that the inclusion map$i : C^{m+1}(\overline{\Omega}) \to C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ is continuous.

> Prove that this map $i$ is not compact. That is, find a sequence that is bounded with respect to the $C^{m+1}(\overline{\Omega})$ norm, but does not contain a convergent subsequence with respect to the $C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ norm.

I have been working through this for a while, trying to construct a counterexample when $n=1$. Although I am beginning to think that the mean value theorem ensures that $i$ actually *is* compact in that case.

Any help with the counterexample is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in one dimension. Let 
$$g_k(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad & x<0; \\ kx, \quad & 0\le x\le 1/k \\ 
1, \quad & x>1/k \end{cases}$$
The function $f_k$ is defined so that $f_k(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f_k^{(m+1)}=g_k$. To get it, 
integrate    $m+1$ times, each time taking the antiderivative that vanishes on the negative axis.

The sequence $(f_k)$ is clearly bounded in $C^{m+1}(-1,1)$. Also, the derivative $f_k^{(m)}$ is given by
$$f_k^{(m)}(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad & x<0; \\ kx^2/2, \quad & 0\le x\le 1/k \\ 
x-1/(2k), \quad & x>1/k \end{cases}$$
This sequence does not converge in the Lipschitz norm. Indeed, if it converged in $C^{0,1}$, the limit
would be the same as the pointwise limit, which is 
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad & x<0; \\   
x, \quad & x\ge 0 \end{cases}$$
But the $C^{0,1}$ norm of $f_k^{(m)}-h$ is at least $1$, because 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|f_k^{(m)}(x)-h(x)|}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|h(x)|}{x} = 1
$$

Comment: Very clear! Good example. Thank you very much.